# Empty base class construction overhead?

Tags: c++, optimization, inheritance, c++11, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Base
{
    public: static int f() {return 42;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    protected: int x;
};

class NotDerived
{
    protected: int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(Base)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<sizeof(Derived)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<sizeof(NotDerived)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With g++ 4.7 -O3, it prints :

```
1
4
4
```

and if I understand that well, it means that Empty Base Class Optimization is enabled.

But my question concerns the runtime overhead : is there any overhead creating (and destructing) a `Derived` object compared to a `NotDerived` object due to the fact that `Derived` should construct/destruct the corresponding `Base` object ?

Comment: I would think so, but I also don't think you should worry about it. You should just use whatever tool is appropriate for your job.  Deal with any optimization during the profiling phase.

Comment: This is a critical aspect for my code. Using an empty base class would help me a lot in terms of design, but as I work in High Performance Computing and as billions of objects of this kind will be created during the execution, I should care about that...

Comment: You should care, but the question for me is whether you should care this early?  Since you have the numbers, have you done some projections to see where you'd be?  It seems if it's that much of a concern at the outset, the best thing you can do is come up with hard numbers for the maximum acceptable hits, then compare them against your compiler, keeping in mind that a different compiler could produce different results...

Comment: It's a good question. Logic would dictate that if there is no additional memory allocated, there is nothing additional to be destroyed, hence it would have no impact. Assembly output supports this, but I imagine since this isn't standardized in any way, any answers you get will be compiler dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the standard makes no guarantees to that there I would consider a compiler that did something different in those cases slightly defective.

There is literally nothing to be done to initialize the base: no memory has to be initialized, no virtual call mechanism has to be set up. No code should be generated for it.

However, you should always check some assembly in a non-trivial setting if this is really important to you.

Answer (score 2):

Any answer to this is going to be implementation dependent, since the standard only specifies the semantics.

However, with any modern compiler and optimizations turned on, I'd expect to see no difference at all.

There's no extra memory to allocate, there's no extra code to run, there's no vtable pointers to change during construction as the extra base is not virtual. Your `Derrived` and `NotDerrived` constructors may well be instruction-for-instruction identical.

With all optimization off you might get a call to an empty `Base::Base()` function on some platforms, but you really shouldn't be worrying about the performance of unoptimized builds.

---

I've put together a small demo on gcc.godbolt.org: http://tinyurl.com/cg8ogym

In short

```
    extern void marker______________________________________();
    // ... 
    marker______________________________________();
    new NotDerived;
    marker______________________________________();
    new Derived;
    marker______________________________________();
```

Compiles to

```
call    marker______________________________________()@PLT
movl    $4, %edi
call    operator new(unsigned long)@PLT
call    marker______________________________________()@PLT
movl    $4, %edi
call    operator new(unsigned long)@PLT
call    marker______________________________________()@PLT
```

If you switch it over to clang, it'll even optimize out the memory allocation

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <unistd.h>

class SlowBase
{
    SlowBase() { ::sleep(5); }

    public: static int f() {return 42;}
};
static_assert( std::is_empty<SlowBase>::value , "SlowBase is empty" );
```

The `Base` class takes **five seconds to construct**!!

```
#include <type_traits>

class FatBase
{
    FatBase() = default;
    int data[1024*1024];    
    public: static int f() {return 42;}
};
static_assert( !std::is_empty<FatBase>::value , "FatBase is not empty" );
```

But this one takes no time!

My point is that construction overhead is not related to how big a class is, it's related to  what the constructor *does*.  `SlowBase` is an empty class but is very slow to construct. `FatBase` is a megabyte in size, but doesn't even zero the array elements so has nothing to do.

In your `Base` example there is an implicitly-declared, trivial default constructor, so it has nothing to do.